# Set variables still return null

Tags: java, string, null

So I did some changes (The generateCsvFile that is giving me the null's is the one at the bottom, I removed the one in my Test() method) but It still says null

```
        private class thehandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource().equals(Nummer)) {
                NummerS = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource() == Locatie) {
                LocatiesS = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource() == Login) {
                LoginS = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource() == Datum) {
                DatumS = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource() == Nummer1) {
                Nummer1S = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource() == Nummer5) {
                Nummer5S = String.format(e.getActionCommand());

            } else if (e.getSource().equals(save)) {
                generateCsvFile("c:\\testss.csv");
                System.out.println(NummerS);
                System.out.println("Debug");
            }

        }

        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the variables got set? Did you debug the code and check that the variables are not null when generateCsvFile is run?

Comment: My guess is that you are comparing objects with "==" and not with equals. So, the strings are not being set in the handler. PS: Please, in future SO questions, start the classes with capital letters and the variables with lower letters.

Comment: Well, I know I did something wrong with setting the variables, but I am still new to Java, and yes the variables are null when I run generateCsvFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the generateCsv() method before you are instantiating your handler. Yes, you are assigning the variables, but you are doing that after you have written the file. Change it to this.

```
public Test() {
    super("Plankske 1");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Nummer = new JTextField(10);
    add(Nummer);

    Locatie = new JTextField("980000119818");
    add(Locatie);

    Login = new JTextField(10);
    add(Login);

    Datum = new JTextField(10);
    add(Datum);

    Nummer1 = new JTextField(10);
    add(Nummer1);

    Nummer5 = new JTextField(10);
    add(Nummer5);

    save = new JButton("Save");
    add(save);


    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    Nummer.addActionListener(handler);
    Locatie.addActionListener(handler);
    Login.addActionListener(handler);
    Datum.addActionListener(handler);
    Nummer1.addActionListener(handler);
    Nummer5.addActionListener(handler);
    save.addActionListener(handler);

    generateCsvFile("c:\\test.csv");

}
```

Comment: Well, that generateCsvFile was not supposed to be there, the one that is bugged is the one at the bottem (I changed my code above)